How to get a branch name for a dedicated changeset number via PowerShell
I am trying to get the branch name for a specific changeset but this information does not exist.
I am using this:
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/tfvc/changesets/16?api-version=7.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/changesets/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP
Is there an option to get the branch?

There's a separate endpoint for branches, but nothing there seems to provide a clue as to how to correlate branches with changesets.

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly get the branch name for a changeset via single Rest API.

Is there an option to get the branch?

Yes. We can use PowerShell script to run the Rest APIs: Changesets - Get Changeset Changes and Branches - Get Branches. Then we can compare the change path and the TFVC branch path to determine which branch the changeset is located.
Here is PowerShell sample:
$token = "PAT"

$ChangesetID = ChangesetID

$OrgName= "OrganizationName"

$ProjName= "ProjectName"

$GetChangesetURL="https://dev.azure.com/$($OrgName)/_apis/tfvc/changesets/$($ChangesetID)/changes?api-version=7.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$GetChangesets= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetChangesetURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

foreach($Changeset in $GetChangesets.value)
{
   $ChangePath = $Changeset.item.path
   echo $ChangePath
   $GetBranchURL="https://dev.azure.com/$($OrgName)/$($ProjName)/_apis/tfvc/branches?api-version=7.1"
   $GetBranches= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetBranchURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json
   foreach($Branch in $GetBranches.value)
   {
     $BranchPath= $Branch.path
     if($ChangePath.Contains($BranchPath))
     {
       echo "$ChangesetID belong to Branch: $BranchPath"
     }
   }


}

Result:
Changeset belong to One TFVC Branch:

Changeset belong to multiple branches:


TFVC changesets are not limited to one branch. A changeset can contain changes that are across multiple branches. To find all the branches for a changeset, all the changes in the set need to be examined.
With the "Changesets - Get" API, a TfvcChangeset is returned which contain a changes member of TfvcChange[].
However, the TfvcChange record doesn't directly provide the branch. You will need to compare the server path of the item with known branches. You will also need to check the VersionControlChangeType to see if the change was a rename or branch creation.
